# Cooking with Ornamental Cabbage (Kale)?

Tags: cabbage

Is it safe to cook Ornamental Cabbage such as this [image: Ornamental_Cabbage]

Should I just pretend its your average cabbage when cooking with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ornamental cabbage is often actually a kale.

See this link with pictures very similar to yours:
http://www.arhomeandgarden.org/plantoftheweek/articles/ornamental_kale.htm

Kale is edible and nutritious but it is tough and very strongly flavored compared to cabbage.

Kale recipes usually involve long braises in flavorful liquid to break down the toughness. Cabbage recipes, which require less cooking lest you release the dreaded sulfur demons, would almost certainly not be sufficient.

Comment: Do you know if ornamental kale differs significantly from normal kale, in texture or flavor?

Comment: I do not know. I have seen and read about it but I haven't actually eaten the ornamental variety.